# Unable to pass querystring in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, response.redirect

This is my code:

```
Response.Redirect("~/partners-card/retailer/retailer-application?rid=" + Request.QueryString["rid"].ToString(), false);
```

its working fine on local machine but on live server it is not passing querystring.
Anyone knows why? Can anyone suggest solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check with the debugger what is in the QueryString?

Comment: Why don't you end the request thread?

Comment: What is the value of ` Request.QueryString["rid"]` when it fails? (BTW: you do have a logging system set up don't you?)

Comment: @Richard I dont know about logging system

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `Response.Redirect(@"~/partners-card...` ?

Comment: Time to learn that if you cannot debug on your sever (highly unlikely in production) you need a different mechanism to see what's going on. And the people who will be responsible for supporting it will thank you if you do production diagnostics and logging well.

Comment: @Markus why? there is nothing in the literal string that requires escaping.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...  confused \ and /...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("yourpage.aspx?rid={0}", Server.UrlEncode(strId)));
```